# Raphael hover event along with resizing box breaks down after third mouseover

Tags: javascript, raphael

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/considerphlebas/G2VKx/).

EDIT: [Here is a better JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/considerphlebas/G2VKx/1/)

The third time I hover over the circle, the rectangle becomes huge and will no longer disappear.

The code to draw the text and rectangle is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771635/wrap-text-to-fit-into-a-rectangle-raphael); I need to have the size of the rectangle depend on the size of the text, I can't define it beforehand.

```
var rsr = Raphael("holder", '1160', '1400');

xpos = 200;
ypos = 200;
rad = 50;

cir = rsr.circle(xpos, ypos, rad);
cir.attr({
        fill: '#444',
      'fill-opacity': 1,
        stroke: 'none'
    });

cir.hover(function() {
  this.animate({ r: rad*1.2 }, 200);
var recttext = rsr.set();
el = rsr.rect(0, 0, 0, 0, 3);
el.attr({fill: '#fff'});
txt = rsr.text(4,10, "Title text").attr({"text-anchor":"start",fill:'#000000',"font-        size": 12});
recttext.push(el);
recttext.push(txt);
var att = {width:recttext.getBBox().width, height:recttext.getBBox().height};
el.attr(att);
recttext.translate(xpos - recttext.getBBox().width/2, ypos - rad - 20);
}, function() {
  this.animate({ r: rad }, 100);
  recttext.remove();
  el.remove();
      txt.remove();
    });
```

Sorry for the code spacing, it got mangled after a few copy/pastes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in your code. The second function returns error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: recttext is not defined
```

because variable `recttext` is not visible in the second function. Similar could happen with variables `el` and `txt`. You did not use `var el = ...` in the first function so it was defined in global space and seen in the second without problem.

You have to move definition of `recttext` out of hover functions (and add variables `el` and `txt`):

```
var recttext, el, txt;

cir.hover(function() {
    this.animate({ r: rad*1.2 }, 200);
    recttext = rsr.set();
    ...
```

In JavaScript, if variable is used for the first time without `var` it is placed in global space. That's why variables `el` and `txt` were seen everywhere. Variable `recttext` was defined with `var` so it was scoped to the first function. Placing them out of hover functions we set them all as global.

Example in jsfiddle still shows flickering. Version used is 2.1.0. With version 2.1.2 there is no flickering. The latest Raphael library is 2.1.2: *Milestone for bug fixes from contributors pull requests.*

Comment: With your help, I'm almost there. (I'm an R and VBA programmer caught in javascript and having some learning curve issues, but you'd think I'd know the difference between a global and local variable.)

The new JSFiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/x9df7/2/ and all that's wrong is I can't figure out how to get the box to reappear.

I really need to get an IDE if I'm going to do this.

Comment: The only change which should be done (comparing to the first improved fiddle example) is: `var recttext, el, txt;`. With this latest example you made it worse.

Comment: I apologize if there is something obvious I'm not getting, but I _think_ I did what you suggested and now on the third hover the box grows huge and starts flickering wildly: http://jsfiddle.net/G2VKx/3/

Comment: Sorry, I thought you also made some other changes. This is strange. Without fiddle it works ok, no flickering. `Title text` box is showing  on top of circle.

Comment: This should be some strange interaction with fiddle. I tested your code in Chrome and Firefox (without fiddle). There is no flickering. Text box is showing on the top of circle. Same with IE10.

Comment: I did the same, loaded it directly in Firefox and the third time I mouseover I get the flicker; I think there's something happening with the .animate method in Raphael. The code I used is here: http://pastebin.com/kmFYgkhu

Comment: Which version of Raphael library do you have. Mine is 2.1.2. Ok, I see from source: it is 2.1.0. Change version in source to 2.1.2 and try. It seems better.

Comment: I got also flickering with version 2.1.0, with 2.1.2 did not.