# Word Wrap in Raphael JS / SVG

Tags: javascript, browser, svg, raphael

How do you get words to wrap inside a box in RaphaelJS?  Or in browser-based SVG in general?

I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/raphaeljs/JgwAHNepo-4) on it, but it doesn't make any sense.  They say to use "widthToCharNum" but as far as I can tell, this thread is the only place those words have ever been used on the internet.  They suggest using a "width" attribute, but this has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text-wrapping is not *built into* Raphael or the SVG spec.  Period.  Coming from the HTML world, I found the absence of text wrapping pretty shocking.

However, you can do it yourself without too much difficulty. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142007/how-to-either-determine-svg-text-box-width-or-force-line-breaks-after-x-chara) for details and an example.  Unfortunately, you have to burn some client-side cycles to make it work dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

The [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) library has a [svg.textflow.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.textflow.js) plugin. It's not ultra fast but it does the trick. It even stores overflowing text in a data attribute so you can use it to create continuously flowing columns. [Here the text flow example page](http://svgjs.com/textflow/).

Comment: The example looks awesome, but the library no longer seems to exist... I've sent a msg to wout to see if he can clarify what's going on with this, as it looked promising!

Answer (score 0):

The tspan tag can give the illusion of word wrap, but there is no built in word wrap functionality.

The tspan tag is identical to the text tag but can be nested inside text tags and inside itself. Coupled with the 'dy' attribute this allows the illusion of word wrap in SVG 1.1. Note that 'dy' is relative to the last glyph (character) drawn. There is a tutorial on how to use tspan at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html.

The article at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/09/11/quint.html might also be useful.

Comment: I don't see 'dy' mentioned in any of these places.  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little belated now, but you might be interested in my [Raphael-paragraph](https://github.com/jbreckmckye/raphael-paragraph) project.

It's a small library that allows you to create auto-wrapped multiline text with maximum width and height constraints, line height and text style configuration. It's still quite beta-ish and requires a lot of optimization, but it should work for your purposes.

Usage examples and documentation are provided on the GitHub page.