# How does "text-align: justify" works?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

Hello I am writing a lib. for creating composition of texts, internal customisation. - [d3-fusiontext](https://github.com/AyanGhatak/d3-fusiontext).

I want to support

> text-align: Justify

The user say provides me a long text. Mentions the height and width it would like to be rendered. The lib. wraps it up, and provides a good visual with wrapped texts. They are all svg text elements so that it can be exported too.

Now I would be to curious to know how the browser internally aligns in a justified manner? Any source/ links/ topics to start with. Any help/ guidance is highly appreciated.

This is a good example of how things might look.

```
codepen.io/anon/pen/zxNJKE
```

P.S: Sorry about no gh-pages and docs as the stuff is under dev. Will update.

Just a generalized curiosity how does the browser determines the spacings in justified alignment?

Comment: There's no text-align property in SVG, it's a html only thing. https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html lists SVG CSS properties.

Comment: Right @RobertLongson, In case we want to support that for SVG. lets writting the logic for it, do we have some papers/ studies to start? Like I am interested to know the way or algo in which HTML beautifies it?

Comment: If you are into developing your own library, you should really delve into the spec! The sections on [*16.2 Alignment: the 'text-align' property*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop) from *CSS 2.1* and [*Alignment and Justification*](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#justification) from *CSS Text Module Level 3* should answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are other answers on SO which provide information on how you can do text wrapping.

- [Word Wrap in Raphael JS / SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378611/word-wrap-in-raphael-js-svg)
- [How to either determine SVG text box width, or force line breaks after 'x' characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142007/how-to-either-determine-svg-text-box-width-or-force-line-breaks-after-x-chara)

Once you work out which characters/words fit on the line, you can use the [`textLength`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#text-TextElementTextLengthAttribute) and [`lengthAdjust`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#text-TextElementLengthAdjustAttribute) attributes to get SVG to stretch the line to fit the width.

```html
<svg width="10cm" height="3cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <line x1="200" y1="0" x2="200" y2="300" stroke="red"/>
  <line x1="800" y1="0" x2="800" y2="300" stroke="red"/>
  
  <text x="200" y="100" 
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue" >
    Hello, out there
  </text>

  <text x="200" y="170" 
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue"
        textLength="600" lengthAdjust="spacing">
    Hello, out there
  </text>

  <text x="200" y="240" 
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue"
        textLength="600" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">
    Hello, out there
  </text>

  <!-- Show outline of canvas using 'rect' element -->
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="998" height="298"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```