# Automatically wrap text to a width in RaphaelJS?

Tags: html, css, svg, raphael

I am currently trying to add some text, which is added dynamically, using RaphaelJS.  I want the text to break at 200 pixels, then continue on the next line. Just like if you had a regular DIV with a width in HTML.

https://jsfiddle.net/qLvuztcy/

I've tried something like:

```
.text {
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px; //and this
}
```

But that's not how it works, unfortunately. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I know that adding a `\n` to the text will make a new line, but I'm not sure how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

[I found an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27559816/2098652) for Snap.svg which I've modified a bit. It works perfectly, however.

```
function text(x, y, txt, max_width, element_class) {
    var abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøåABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ";
    var temp = rsr.text(50, 50, abc);
    temp.node.classList.add("text");
    var letter_width = temp.getBBox().width / abc.length;
    temp.remove();

    var heights = [];

    var loopLines = txt.split("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < loopLines.length; j++) {
        var words = loopLines[j].split(" ");
        var width_so_far = 0,
            current_line = 0,
            lines = [''];
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            var l = words[i].length;
            if (width_so_far + (l * letter_width) > max_width) {
                lines.push('');
                current_line++;
                width_so_far = 0;
            }
            width_so_far += l * letter_width;
            lines[current_line] += words[i] + " ";
        }

        if (j > 0) {
            y += heights[j - 1];
        }

        lines = lines.join("\n");
        var t = rsr.text(x, y, lines);
        $(t.node).find("tspan").attr("dy", "1.2em");
        t.node.classList.add(element_class);
        heights.push(t.getBBox().height);
    }
}
```

Requires jQuery, as I am doing the `find("tspan")` with jQuery (might as well, since I use it other places as well).

I've modified it to now support `\n` in your strings as well.

Answer (score -2):

SVG doesn't have automatic text wrapping.  Well not in the current version anyway.

You have to split the text up into lines yourself.  Or if you are displaying the SVG in a browser, you have the option of embedding HTML in the SVG. You can do this with the `<foreignObject>` element.

I'm not sure whether Raphael has an API for creating `foreignObject` elements.  You'll need to investigate.

Comment: I cannot accept or upvote this as an answer, because it doesn't answer my question. I found a workaround for [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) which I have implemented and I am testing now. I'll post an answer.

Comment: And now you mark it as a duplicate to a whole different library. Good job, Paul. Literally butthurt.

Comment: Fine. There you go. Happy? I marked it dup because the answers were nearly identical and I believe that other person deserved the credit.  I also note you downvoted me out of spite despite the fact that your answer does exactly what I said you had to.

Comment: Using `<foreignObject>` is the last thing you want to do, if you plan on being compatible with most browsers. I downvoted you because your answer didn't give me any new information. I know SVG doesn't have text wrapping. I know I probably had to do this by looping through all the lines. I knew **not** to use `<foreignObject>`, despite you saying so. You clearly don't know anything about Raphael text wrapping, which is why I downvoted your comment.

Comment: You sure knew a lot of things. Pity you didn't mention any of it in your question.

Comment: So I should mention that I know SVG doesn't have wrapping and that I *probably* knew I had to loop through the elements, but that I didn't know how to achieve it? Oh wait, I did say I didn't know how to achieve what I want. I did say adding `\n` adds a new line. If you add all of that up, you would see I knew most of it already. But please don't argue. There's no point.